# Multiple sta threads not working in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a Windows Form application which is connecting with different attendance machines and handling real time attendance events. Application works well with one machine. But with multiple machines attendance for one machine is cached by both threads but I want that one thread handles only one machine event. And I want that all threads work using single windows form not multiple forms.How to handle multiple machine connections in separate threads. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using zkemkeeper;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         private System.Timers.Timer timer1 = null;
        string filePath = @"E:\file1.txt";
        bool connSatus = false;
        CZKEMClass axCZKEM1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 30000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;


            Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
                connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("162.36.2.24", 4370);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("HR Machine is connected  at the" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (connSatus == true)
                {
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify2);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected2);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction2);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx2);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected2);
                    if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify2);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx2);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction2);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected2);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected2);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Application.Run();
            });
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();



            Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread2 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
                connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("162.36.2.22", 4370);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Audit Machine is connected  at the" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (connSatus == true)
                {
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected);
                    if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Application.Run();
            });
            createComAndMessagePumpThread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            createComAndMessagePumpThread2.Start();


        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                  /*  connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("172.16.3.2", 4370);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Machine is connected successfully on" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                        writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    if (connSatus == true)
                    {
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected);
                        //  this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected);
                        if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                        {
                            this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                            this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                            //   this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                            this.axCZKEM1.OnConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnConnected);
                            this.axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected);
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                            }

                        }
                    }*/
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected()
        {
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnDisConnected Has been Triggered");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Machine is disconnected");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(string sEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond, int iWorkCode)
        {
            // if (OnAttTransactionEx != null) OnAttTransactionEx(sEnrollNumber, iIsInValid, iAttState, iVerifyMethod, iYear, iMonth, iDay, iHour, iMinute, iSecond, iWorkCode, axCZKEM1.MachineNumber, Tag);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasactionEx Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + sEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnConnected()
        {
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnConnected Has been Triggered");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" machine connected event is triggered sucessfully.");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnVerify(int iUserID)
        {

            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnVerify Has been Triggered,Verifying...");
            if (iUserID != -1)
            {

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User is veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User is not veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction(int iEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasaction Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + iEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnAttTrasaction Has been Triggered,Verified OK");
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...UserID:" + iEnrollNumber.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...isInvalid:" + iIsInValid.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...attState:" + iAttState.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...VerifyMethod:" + iVerifyMethod.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...Time:" + iYear.ToString() + "-" + iMonth.ToString() + "-" + iDay.ToString() + " " + " " + iHour.ToString() + ":" + iMinute.ToString() + ":" + iSecond.ToString());
        }





        private void axCZKEM1_OnDisConnected2()
        {
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnDisConnected Has been Triggered");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Machine2 is disconnected");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx2(string sEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond, int iWorkCode)
        {
            // if (OnAttTransactionEx != null) OnAttTransactionEx(sEnrollNumber, iIsInValid, iAttState, iVerifyMethod, iYear, iMonth, iDay, iHour, iMinute, iSecond, iWorkCode, axCZKEM1.MachineNumber, Tag);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasactionEx2 Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + sEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnConnected2()
        {
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnConnected Has been Triggered");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" machine2 connected event is triggered sucessfully.");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnVerify2(int iUserID)
        {

            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnVerify Has been Triggered,Verifying...");
            if (iUserID != -1)
            {

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User mach2 is veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User mach2 is not veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction2(int iEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasaction2 Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + iEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("RTEvent OnAttTrasaction Has been Triggered,Verified OK");
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...UserID:" + iEnrollNumber.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...isInvalid:" + iIsInValid.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...attState:" + iAttState.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...VerifyMethod:" + iVerifyMethod.ToString());
            //lbRTShow.Items.Add("...Time:" + iYear.ToString() + "-" + iMonth.ToString() + "-" + iDay.ToString() + " " + " " + iHour.ToString() + ":" + iMinute.ToString() + ":" + iSecond.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Async Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx)?

Comment: I am looking to connect with multiple machines in separate threads. Register separate events for each machine. Now one event attendance transaction is working for all machines?? despite the fact that they are in separate threads.

Comment: You can create a class for handling events and do the necessary work. Then, create as many instances of this class needed. Now you can utilize Async Task for each of handler instances to perform your task. Review example in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have declared only one CZKEMClass instance but you are using two devices. If you have two devices and you need real time handling of attendance events for these devices, you must declare separate CZKEMClass instances for each device to fire/capture the events from each device. Therefore, in your case you need to declare two CZKEMClass instances because you have two devices.

Here's your example code updated to include two CZKEMClass instances:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using zkemkeeper;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string filePath = @"E:\file1.txt";
        bool connSatus = false;
        CZKEMClass axCZKEM1, axCZKEM2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                axCZKEM1 = new CZKEMClass();
                connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("162.36.2.24", 4370);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("HR Machine is connected  at the" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (connSatus == true)
                {
                    axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                    axCZKEM1.OnConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                    axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                    axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx);
                    axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                    if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                        axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx2;
                        axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                        axCZKEM1.OnConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                        axCZKEM1.OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Application.Run();
            });
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();


            Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                axCZKEM2 = new CZKEMClass();
                connSatus = axCZKEM2.Connect_Net("162.36.2.22", 4370);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("HR Machine is connected  at the" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (connSatus == true)
                {
                    axCZKEM2.OnVerify -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                    axCZKEM2.OnConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                    axCZKEM2.OnAttTransaction -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                    axCZKEM2.OnAttTransactionEx -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx);
                    axCZKEM2.OnDisConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                    if (axCZKEM2.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        axCZKEM2.OnVerify += new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                        axCZKEM2.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx2;
                        axCZKEM2.OnAttTransaction += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                        axCZKEM2.OnConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                        axCZKEM2.OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Application.Run();
            });
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();
        }

        private void OnDisConnected()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Machine is disconnected");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void OnAttTransactionEx(string sEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond, int iWorkCode)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasactionEx Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + sEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void OnConnected()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" machine connected event is triggered sucessfully.");
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        private void OnVerify(int iUserID)
        {
            if (iUserID != -1)
            {

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User is veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(" User is not veified sucessfully.");
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        private void OnAttTransaction(int iEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasaction Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + iEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting large code only answers is not helpful. Some detailed explanation of what you have changed in the code to resolve the issue would be more useful. As it stands, it's not obvious at all whether you have actually changed anything at all.

Comment: No i changed  you can see i declare two CZKEMClass

Comment: I'm not denying that you haven't changed anything, but that is a lot of code to go through without any directions. You need to explain why declaring two `CZKEMClass` actually solves the question asked. Providing working code is not helpful if there is no explanation as to why it works/solves the issue, so that the person who asked the question can understand what he/she had done wrong in the first place. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41816140/edit) your question and add some paragraphs detailing this.

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution for you
firs define global variable like that

```
IDictionary<string, CZKEMClass> device2FingersList = new Dictionary<string, CZKEMClass>();
```

Then your code

```
Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                device2FingersList[deviceIp] = new CZKEMClass();
                connSatus = device2FingersList[deviceIp].Connect_Net(deviceIp, 4370);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("HR Machine is connected  at the" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (connSatus == true)
                {
                    device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnVerify -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                    device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                    device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnAttTransaction -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                    device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnAttTransactionEx -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx);
                    device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnDisConnected -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                    if (device2FingersList[deviceIp].RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnVerify += new _IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(OnVerify);
                        device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(OnAttTransactionEx2;
                        device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnAttTransaction += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(OnAttTransaction);
                        device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(OnConnected);
                        device2FingersList[deviceIp].OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(OnDisConnected);
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("attendnce transaction Events are registered... ");
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Application.Run();
            });
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: deviceIp is which ip you want to connect